# Using QueryDSL, how to compare two Joda DateTimes (persisted in Postgres using JPA and Jadira) in different time zones?

Tags: jpa, timezone, jodatime, querydsl

I am trying to compare same dates stored in different time zones (e.g. 2pm New York and 1pm Chicago) using Querydsl but running into issues when persisting dates as Joda Time `org.joda.time.DateTime`, works great when persisting as `java.util.Calendar` though. Here is the entity class, relevant parts of it:

```
public class AvailabilityCalendarEvent {

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Columns(columns = { 
            @Column(name = "end_time"),
            @Column(name = "end_time_zone") 
        })
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone")
    private org.joda.time.DateTime end;

    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Calendar start;

    // omitted code
}
```

The `start` field is a Calendar and `end` is DateTime. This test persist a time in Chicago and then tries to find it using the same time in New York (offset by 1 hour to account for difference in time zones), works as expected.

```
@Test
    public void testDateEqualityUsingCalendar() {
        Calendar chicagoTime = new DateTime(2016, 1, 13, 15, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago")).toCalendar(null);
        AvailabilityCalendarEvent chicagoCalendarEvent = new AvailabilityCalendarEvent();
        chicagoCalendarEvent.setStart(chicagoTime);

        calendarEventRepository.save(chicagoCalendarEvent);

        Calendar laTime = new DateTime(2016, 1, 13, 13, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles")).toCalendar(null);

        ArrayList<CalendarEvent> retrievedCalendarEvents = Lists.newArrayList(calendarEventRepository.findAll(QCalendarEvent.qCalendarEvent.start.eq(laTime)));
        assertEquals(1, retrievedCalendarEvents.size()); // Passes
    }
```

This test does the exact same thing as the start date test, except it compares end dates which are stored using `DateTime`, it fails.

```
@Test
public void testDateEqualityUsingDateTime() {
    DateTime chicagoTime = new DateTime(2016, 1, 13, 15, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"));
    AvailabilityCalendarEvent chicagoCalendarEvent = new AvailabilityCalendarEvent();
    chicagoCalendarEvent.setEnd(chicagoTime);

    calendarEventRepository.save(chicagoCalendarEvent);

    DateTime laTime = new DateTime(2016, 1, 13, 13, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles"));

    ArrayList<CalendarEvent> retrievedCalendarEvents = Lists.newArrayList(calendarEventRepository.findAll(QCalendarEvent.qCalendarEvent.end.eq(laTime)));
    assertEquals(1, retrievedCalendarEvents.size()); // Fails
}
```

Any ideas why it is happening or how to fix?

Also, I verified that doing a 'manual' SQL compare on those same DateTime dates passes when timestamps and timezones are concatenated:

`select * 
from calendar_event ce 
inner join calendar_event ce1 on 
  (ce.end_time || ' ' || ce.end_time_zone)::Timestamptz = 
  (ce1.end_time || ' ' || ce1.end_time_zone)::Timestamptz 
  and ce.id != ce1.id;`

Comment: The actual SQL to render the comparison is rendered by the JPA provider and seems to be incorrect in this case. How does the SQL of the end comparison look like?